# What's the state of the art for encrypting/decrypting passwords in a .Net RestApi in 2017?

Tags: c#, encryption

I need to store username/passwords in a database for several .Net applications and I'd like to know whats the state of the art for this issue these days, since every answered I've found is really old. 
I've read that passwords must not be decrypted after being encrypted, I assume that. I've also heard about libsodium. I don't need help on how to do it, I just need help regarding best practices (hashing with salt is my option for the moment) and clarification with respect to the idea of corporations not storing passwords in their databases anymore but using instead external systems (OpenID, Facebook, Google...). Could anyone clarify? 
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: [This question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) is now 7 years old, however I believe most of the information is still relevant. As far as I can see OWASP [now recommend using the Argon2 password hashing algorithm](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: I already had read the question but thanks very much for the OWASP reference... I can work from there... Thankx!